# What is the purpose of aura:set in the example?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, force.com, sfdc

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contactlist}" var="con">
       <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-p-around_small">
         <lightning:card title="{!con.LastName}" footer="{!con.Email}" iconName="standard:contact">
           <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button name="{!con.Id}" label="view details" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.doredirect}"></lightning:button>
           </aura:set>
         <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
         {!con.FirstName}  {!con.LastName}
         </p>
         <br/>
        </lightning:card>
      </div>
     </aura:iteration>
```

As the **lightning:button** already has **onClick** to trigger the controller function, then why do we need **<aura:set attribute="actions">** ?

Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "set" isn't there to modify the button. It gives you a way to inject stuff into right places on the lightning:card. That way your buttons will be shown consistent with other cards in the system. Otherwise you'd have to put the buttons somewhere in card's body? Or recreate whole styling manually (you could use LDS but what if style changes in future)?

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_facets.htm
You can use same trick to build your own reusable components where you just inject little changes. LWC uses similar thing but it's called "slots" instead of "facets".

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) So, it is for the purpose of styling?

Comment: Putting your custom functionality in right placeholders they have planned in the library. Like 2nd and 4th example in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:card/documentation - if you need "title" to have some styling, not be just text - how you'd pass it?  You can't write html inside the `title="<b>test</b>"`, won't compile. Or if you'd want a link in footer, how would you do it. Inject facets like they provided or make whole component from scratch